# Android camera2 high speed capture

Tags: android, android-camera2

OK, I'm trying to implement a high-speed capture on Android phone. The info on how to do it is very spare. There are google examples that are useless, because due to frequent API changes they don't compile anymore (and anyway - require a ridiculous amount of bloat - why would I need navigation library that breaks the gradle build system, if all I need to do is capture a video?!). There is ONE Chinese tutorial that mentions an app called GeekCamera2, that is very promising, but when I found and downloaded GeekCamera2 source code, everything that had anything to do with high speed capture was commented out. I have a piece of code that can do the normal capture, but as soon as I try the code that uses `createHighSpeedRequestList` and `setRepeatingBurst` it doesn't seem to do anything, the recording session just stops almost immediately. No crash, no error in logcat.

Update - Google's own Camera2 high speed capture from here: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2SlowMotion works only on Samsung S10, doesn't work on any new device I have (all devices with highs speed capture)

```
E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 4 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
E/CameraManagerGlobal: Camera 5 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
E/CameraFragment: Camera 0 error: (4) Fatal (device)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera 0 error: (4) Fatal (device)
at com.example.android.camera2.slowmo.fragments.CameraFragment$openCamera$2$1.onError(CameraFragment.kt:405)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1893)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.$r8$lambda$KBQCqQRdhVVn7uHI9Xdha6OqnsU(Unknown Source:0)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:241)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:358)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating:
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2510)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1377)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:596)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:808)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:284)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:241)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:358)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

So - is there anyone who was able to use this API in 2022/2023?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do the basic case of having two outputs:

1. Preview to display (30fps)
2. High-speed video recording to disk (120/240fps)

If so, one source to look at is Android'd official compliance tests, that aim to verify the feature works on devices that support it:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/camera/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/RecordingTest.java;drc=409e62101c9c22c18547efabffebe47a9e9adc5c;l=1174

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but all of the devices I tried support several high speed modes, from 120 to 480 fps.